# how google "understand" that i already have been login to google service(like gmail)

Tags: google-api, google-signin, google-oauth

I have a case:
It was opened Gmail in one tab of the browser. All good, I can use Gmail(send, receive ...).

I create a simple HTML page from the guide for Google Sign-In, also add an iframe with link to the google data studio file
I open another tab in the same browser and load this simple HTML page. In JS code onload handler of Google SignIn library i do:

```
gapi.auth2.init({client_id: factory.clientId,scope: 'profile email'});
var authInst = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
var isLoggedIn = authInst.isSignedIn.get();
```

**===> i get false, so library assume that i dont signed in.**

But the content of iframe(link to the google data studio file which located in my Google account) is loading and i can see data of the GDS file. So I assume that Google somehow handles my session data on their servers.

How can I align result from `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()` call of the library or which library should i use to understand the REAL state of the user(signed in or not)? How to handle this case in the right way?

Also, due to restrictions, i cant parse the content of the loaded iframe with js iframe.contentDocument property